# Select distinct combination of two fields with a condition in MongoDB (Node JS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this kind of collection named **'Message'**

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62641aea1fbe19349f8fba78"),
    text: 'Hello',
    user: new ObjectId("625b8f00e2464fb758263b4d"),
    receiver: new ObjectId("62638d3e5bcd98e7e48ca1b7"),
    createdAt: 2022-04-23T15:27:38.270Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-04-23T15:27:38.270Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6264256fc0ee5093f8d994a0"),
    text: 'Hi',
    user: new ObjectId("62638f1495b841266161b032"),
    receiver: new ObjectId("62638d3e5bcd98e7e48ca1b7"),
    createdAt: 2022-04-23T16:12:31.155Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-04-23T16:12:31.155Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62642dc05318104caabbdecc"),
    text: 'Hi',
    user: new ObjectId("625b8f00e2464fb758263b4d"),
    receiver: new ObjectId("62638d3e5bcd98e7e48ca1b7"),
    createdAt: 2022-04-23T16:48:00.416Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-04-23T16:48:00.416Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

here **user** is the sender and the other one **receiver**. If my user id is **"myId"**,
I want to retrieve distinct combinations of **user** and **receiver** of my message objects which means with a condition of **user == myID or receiver == myId**.

Expected values.

```
[
  {
    user: new ObjectId("625b8f00e2464fb758263b4d"),
    receiver: new ObjectId("62638d3e5bcd98e7e48ca1b7")
  },
  {
    user: new ObjectId("62638f1495b841266161b032"),
    receiver: new ObjectId("62638d3e5bcd98e7e48ca1b7")
  }
]
```

So I'm new to MongoDB, **is there any possible way to do that?** or is there anything I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Sandeep Vithanage,
You can do something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          user: myId
        },
        {
          receiver: myId
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        user: "$user",
        receiver: "$receiver"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      "newRoot": "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see working on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ow4N4UbO0sK).
This is an aggregation pipeline. The first step is to match the cases you asked for. The second one is to group them by combinations of users and receivers. The third one is just formatting.

Answer (score 0):

using $match and $project like below:

```
await Model.aggregate([{ 
     $match: { 
       $or: [
         {user: 'myid'},
         {receiver: 'myid'}
       ] } 
     },
     $project: {user: 1, receiver: 1}
])
```